# Simple pool of threads which calculate the sum of a given number from the main process

Tags: c, pthreads

I have to make a program which creates a number of threads that are waiting at the beginning, then the main process creates a doubly linked list where random numbers are put and then a signal tells the threads that a number has been put in the list, then the threads should "process" these numbers (is simply calculate the sum from 0 to the given number), graphically it looks like this:

[image]

And here is the code, I wonder if I'm doing what I'm doing fine...

**Note**: I'm working with 4 threads and the sleep(1) was to see the output...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#include "double_linked_list.h"

void *sum(void *ptr);

sem_t semaphore;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

int main() {
    sem_init(&semaphore, 0, 0);

    int threads = 4;
    int number, i;

    pthread_t *threads_tab;
    int *thread_args;

    threads_tab = malloc(threads * sizeof(pthread_t));
    thread_args = malloc(threads * sizeof(int));

    srand(time(NULL));

    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        thread_args[i] = i;
        pthread_create(&threads_tab[i], NULL, sum, (void*) &thread_args[i]);
    }

    while (1) {
        number = rand() % 100;

        printf("Insertando: %d\n", number);
        InsertAtHead(number);

        sem_post(&semaphore);

        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}

void *sum(void *ptr) {
    int i, acumulator, number;

    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&semaphore);

        acumulator = 0;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        number = tail->data;
        PopTail();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        for (i = 0; i < number + 1; i++)
            acumulator += i;

        printf("The number is: %d and the result is: %d from thread: %d\n", number, acumulator, *(int *)ptr);
    }
}
```

Apparently it's working well, it doesn't generate any errors and the outputs are the expected ones, but I would like to hear more opinions, because I am new in this, perhaps I'm making some mistakes without realizing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing the code for `InsertHead` and `PopTail`, but I would not be surprised if you've got a race condition between the main thread's `InsertHead` and the worker thread's `PopTail`. The workers take `mutex` in order to prevent data races among themselves; but the main thread blithely pushes new data *onto* the list without taking `mutex`, which *seems* like it would cause a race in the case that the list had only one element.

---

Stylistically, I'd replace

```
int threads = 4;
int number, i;

pthread_t *threads_tab;
int *thread_args;

threads_tab = malloc(threads * sizeof(pthread_t));
thread_args = malloc(threads * sizeof(int));
```

with

```
pthread_t threads_tab[4];
int thread_args[4];
```

to save those heap allocations (which, by the way, you never `free`).

The variable `i` should be declared within the `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
```

and the variable `number` should be declared where it's used:

```
int number = rand() % 100;
```

---

```
thread_args[i] = i;
pthread_create(&threads_tab[i], NULL, sum, (void*) &thread_args[i]);
[...]
printf(..., *(int *)ptr);
```

This is fine (and 100% correct, because it avoids implementation-defined casts!), but you should know that in practice most codebases will do simply

```
pthread_create(&threads_tab[i], NULL, sum, (void*) i);
[...]
printf(..., (int)ptr);
```

The latter is *technically* implementation-defined, but on common platforms it works, and it works without any memory loads or stores, which is nice, so that's why people end up doing it.

---

You fail to check the return value of `pthread_create`, which is a pretty big deal in real code; it's easy for a process to run out of threads. See [`man pthread_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html).

---

In English, `accumulator` has two `c`s.

Comment: Although, seeing your answer more carefully, I don't agree with the `for (int i = 0; i <threads; i ++)` and `int number = rand ()% 100`. It's not necessary to do it that way, and BTW it's only allowed in the standard c99 and above

Comment: Defining your variables at their point-of-use isn't *necessary*, but then neither is naming them `i` instead of, say, `marypoppins`. It's simply *better* to name the loop variable `i` and define it in the looping statement.

Comment: "BTW it's only allowed in the standard c99 and above" — True. However, note that 1999 was 17 years ago. There do still exist codebases which need to conform to the 1989 standard, but that's a very small niche occupied mainly by very long-bearded people. If you personally were in that niche, trust me, you wouldn't be asking this type of question on CodeReview.

Comment: At least in my case, to be able to compile `for (int i = 0; i <threads; i ++)` I have to put the flag `-std=c99`, so I prefer to do the definition of `i` firt and then initialize it in the loop for